# Android Pixel 4a distorted launch image

Tags: android, ionic-framework

I am seeing the launch image distorted of a released app on the new Pixel 4A. The `app/src/main/res` folder has all of the correctly sized `splash.png` files as drawables. Has anyone seen this or have a suggestion? Attached images are 1,280x1,920 `drawable-port-xxxhdpi/splash.png` file and screen shot from the Pixel 4a.
[image: splash.png]
[image: screen shot Pixel 4a]

Comment: I am using compileSdkVersion and targetSdkVersion both set to 29, but tried 30 as well.